# Regression discontinuity vs propensity score matching

Tags: regression, inference, causality, propensity-scores, regression-discontinuity

I have recently read some pieces suggesting that **regression discontinuity designs** could be the best statistical approach for causal inference stemming from non-randomized studies (eg [1](https://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/971433?) and [2](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamainternalmedicine/fullarticle/2778363)).

However, as far as I am aware, the strongest claim for accuracy and validity has been made so far for **propensity score matching** (and possibly inverse probability of treatment weighting) (eg [3](https://www.arthroscopyjournal.org/article/S0749-8063(21)00820-3/fulltext))

Thus, *what is the comparative accuracy and validity of regression discontinuity vs propensity score matching?*

Comment: If their assumptions are met, either is valid.  The questions are: 1) how robust are they to violations of their assumptions; 2) a-priori, how likely is it their assumptions would hold in a given situation; & 3) how efficiently do they use the data you have?

Comment: Those two approaches are for much different settings and neither of them "does" causal inference.  They both do _conditional_ causal inference, conditional on adjusting for the right variables.  And there are many reasons not to do propensity score analysis, covered [here](http://hbiostat.org/bbr/md/propensity.html#misunderstandings-about-propensity-scores).